# detect Media Recording API support using java script

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to check if the browser running my javascript code has support for the media recording api in a programmatic way? For example, I can run `navigator.userAgent` to detect the OS and the browser info, but is there a way to do the same for the media recording api? If so what is it?

Comment: The same as in most such cases …? You check whether the objects/method you want to use exist ...

Comment: You could also have a look at how detection libraries such a Modernizer do this for this particular feature.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet, taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API).

```js
if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
   console.log('getUserMedia supported.');
} else {
   console.log('getUserMedia not supported on your browser!');
}
```